# Entity Framework Core Data Type Conversion differences between SQLite vs SQLServer

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a **SQLite** and **SQL Express** databases both of which have a table with the columns as below:

[image]

my simplified Entity look as below:

```
public class Customer
{
   public string BusinessIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

if you notice the datatype is different between the Database `bigint` vs `string` on my entity for an example.

I have used a `Fluent API` to do the mapping as shown below:

`entity.Property(p => p.BusinessIdentifier).HasColumnName("CUSTOMER")`

on the **SQLite** when i use `options.UseSqlite(connectionString);` this work just fine. For SQLite `connectionString="Data Source=my_db.db"`

however when I use **SQL Server Express** using `options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);` it starts to give me errors on the type mismatch.

I have to explicitly handle this conversion on the *Fluent API* as below:

`entity.Property(p => p.BusinessIdentifier).HasColumnName("CUSTOMER").HasConversion(v => Convert.ToInt64(v), v => v.ToString());`

SQL Server `connectionString="Data Source=my_machine\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=my_db;Integrated Security=True;"`

**Question**:

Can someone please explain why is this difference between the 2 types of databases and is it really needed to be so specific in every case?

Regards
Kiran

Comment: I think you can use `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` with the property or similar

Comment: but how does it work in SQLite, its the same EF code on either of the database, I am wondering how it works on one but fails on another

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not force for data type constraints, It allows you the store a value which is of different data type, so this might be the reason that your code works fine with SQLite, On the other hand, SQL Server enforces you to have to the same datatype.

You can refer to this doc https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.